# No tests found for given includes: [***Test](filter.includeTestsMatching)

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, testcase

I am using *Intellij 2019.2* to run gradle test cases, however, I keep getting the following exception. According to some posts, I have done the following:

1. Add `junit(junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1)` dependencies as `testImplementation`
   and
2. Put `useJUnitPlatform()` in `build.gradle` file
3. Set Intellij's gradle runner to use Gradle(Default) to run my test cases.

The issue still exist after above steps.

Could someone give me some hint about how to get rid of this error ? Really appreciate

````
   Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestExecutionException: No tests found for given includes: [***Test](filter.includeTestsMatching)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.NoMatchingTestsReporter.afterSuite(NoMatchingTestsReporter.java:37)
                at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor307.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
                at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
                at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
                at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
                at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
                at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
                at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
                at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
                at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
                at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
                at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy99.afterSuite(Unknown Source)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.TestListenerAdapter.completed(TestListenerAdapter.java:48)
                at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor325.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
                at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
                at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
                at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
                at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
                at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
                at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
                at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
                at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
                at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
                at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101.completed(Unknown Source)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.completed(StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.java:96)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.AttachParentTestResultProcessor.completed(AttachParentTestResultProcessor.java:56)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.processors.TestMainAction.run(TestMainAction.java:60)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.DefaultTestExecuter.execute(DefaultTestExecuter.java:116)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.DefaultTestExecuter.execute(DefaultTestExecuter.java:51)
                at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.AbstractTestTask.executeTests(AbstractTestTask.java:483)
                at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.executeTests(Test.java:587)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:48)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:705)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:672)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$4.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:338)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:327)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:312)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:75)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:158)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:46)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:49)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:42)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:28)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:133)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$5(CacheStep.java:83)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:82)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:37)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.PrepareCachingStep.execute(PrepareCachingStep.java:33)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:38)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:23)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:95)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:88)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
                ... 129 more```
````

Comment: Does it work from command-line? Do you have tests matching `src/test/java/**/*Test.java`? etc

Comment: @drekbour In my Intellij, I have both java 1.8 and java 11.0.4. This project needs to be run using java 11.0.4. Intellij is using C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3\jbr as JDK home path. Do you think this is the issue? I am not able to run test cases using command line since I don't have Java 11 installed on my computer.

Comment: Is it possible to provide little sample project where the issue is reproduced?

Comment: I had the same problem and resolved selecting the option menu "Create Test Configuration" that appears between the "Run ... with Coverage" and "Show in explorer" option when select a test file and right click to show the menu.

Answer (score 26):

I'm not sure if this will help, but I changed the import statement on my test class, for the test decorator, from `import org.junit.Test` to `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` and that seems to have fixed this problem.

Answer (score 14):

Just add

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

to your app

> build.gradle > root

file. In my case I had following for logging:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events("passed", "skipped", "failed")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Faced this issue after upgrading to Android Studio Chipmunk. Resolved it by REMOVING the following code from module's `build.gradle`:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Looks like this configuration was one of the ways to resolve this issue on the prior versions of Android Studio (or AGP), but became a source of the problem by itself due to some new changes.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. After running gradle in debug mode `--debug` mode, the console was containing a `ClassNotFoundException` for `org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException`.

Issue was fixed by adding:

```
testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.5.2'
```

Comment: Question is, why is an error like `ClassNotFoundException` visible only at debug level? It's been a while, but any chance you can post the complete log statement? Gradle debug spits out so much garbage it's almost unusable.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. Initially, I had 2 dependencies in my Gradle project because of that I was getting the issue. The first two dependencies were the following :

```
compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.8"
testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4"
```

Then I added 3rd dependency which resolved the issue.

```
testCompile platform("org.spockframework:spock-bom:2.0-M1-groovy-2.5")
```

Answer (score 2):

It was making all the test functions public that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

One of the causes of this Exception is using **Default** access modifier in Java.

JUnit test methods should avoid the following: declared static, not declared public, do not return void, or have parameters.

Such test methods are easy to create inadvertently, but they will not be executed by JUnit test runners.

So instead of this:

```
@Test
void test() {
   assertEquals(1, 1);
}
```

Add **public** like this:

```
@Test
public void test() {
   assertEquals(1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error today in one of our projects. After a couple of moments of trying to figure out what was happened, I saw that in my case the problem was the JUnit version that I was using. After migrating to JUnit version '5.8.1' all of my tests stop running, so I did a roll back to version 5.3.1

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this issue was being caused by Robolectric 4.8, which didn't support targetSdkVersion 33. Upgrading to Robolectric 4.9 solved the issue. I was able to notice the issue by running the test on the test class instead of the method, which gave the targetSdkVersion=33 > maxSdkVersion=32 error message.