# test events were not received and android studio not picking junit test runner

Tags: android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, junit5

I am trying to run JUnit 5 tests on android studio bumblebee. I want to run these using JUnitTest runner instead of gradle test runner. but android studio is picking gradle as test runner. And tests are not running with error Test events were not received

> *FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'. No tests found for given
> includes:
> com.example.sampleproject.ExampleTest*

I looked at many answers on internet but no luck.

build.gradle (Project)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

build.gradle (app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sampleproject"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.2"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

I am using gradle 7.4.2. I also tried to look for an option run test using (gradle/ intellij) in

`Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> gradle`

but it seems I have less number of options there.

gradle options

[image]

Note : Junit 4 tests are running using gradle runner.

Comment: Try to run it via IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1. Does it work better?

Comment: Faced the same issue after upgrading to Chipmunk. Resolved this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73424783/2463035